# $push an object to a nested array

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am looking for a way to $push an object to a nested array which the route keys come from variables.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ce9964cd0e7df57eb0c8a99"
    },
    "history": {
        "2019": {
            "jan": {
                "1": [],
                "2": [],
                "3": []
            },
            "feb": {
                "1": [],
                "2": [],
                "3": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```py
def add_tx():
    body = request.get_json()
    users = mongo.db.date
    users.find_one_and_update({
        "username": session['username']
    }, {
        '$push': {
            'history'[str(body['year'])][months[body['month']]][str(
                body['day'])]: {body['title']: body['value']}
        }
    })
```

So the route in the "history" object comes from the body:

`body['year'], body['month'], body['day']`

and I want to append to the array an object with:

`{body['title']: body['value']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it, for someone else that could be looking for the answer;

the trick is to set a variable with the wanted path using the variables and the wanted value then push only that final variable.

```py
    # Setting the variable with the complete path in the DB using the variables from the POST BODY
    query = {}
    query['history.' + str(body['year']) + "." + months[body['month']] +
          "." + str(body['day'])] = {body['title']: float(body['value'])}
    # Pushing the created variable to the DB
    users.find_one_and_update({
        "username": session['username']
    }, {
        '$push': query
    })
```